# How to execute java application avoiding compilation output to be displayed?

Tags: java, background, terminal

I have to execute a java application on a remote server through command line.

I normally run the application like:

```
java -jar /home/user/files/simulator.jar -nogui:/home/user/files/my-sims/sim1.csc
```

this prints in my terminal a lot of compilation outputs, and during the simulation it prints the simulation time remaining every 1% increase of the simulation progress.

Obviously, during the simulation the terminal is unusable due to these outputs.

I tried to run the application with a & at the end to run it in background, like:

```
java -jar /home/user/files/simulator.jar -nogui:/home/user/files/my-sims/sim1.csc &
```

but the compilation outputs are printed anyway, so I cannot use the terminal to logout from the server.

How can I solve?

Thanks

Comment: what about piping the output to /dev/null?  `java -jar ... 2>&/dev/null`

Comment: What platform are you in?

Comment: @Mohayemin Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On linux, direct the output to `/dev/null`

```
java -jar /home/user/files/simulator.jar -nogui:/home/user/files/my-sims/sim1.csc > /dev/null
```

To skip the errors on consol, add an &

```
java -jar /home/user/files/simulator.jar -nogui:/home/user/files/my-sims/sim1.csc &> /dev/null
```

The answer is borrowed from [serverfault.](https://serverfault.com/a/41968/155207)

Comment: @aliants: What do you mean by terminal locked? Are the outputs still printed?

Comment: It doesn't return to user@user-VPCEB4B4E but it remains the rectangular character blinking (sorry for my bad explanation but I'm not able to tell it in english).

Comment: Ok, I solved with another & at the end.

    java -jar /home/user/files/simulator.jar -nogui:/home/user/files/my-sims/sim1.csc &> /dev/null &     Thanks a lot.

Comment: Well yes, that will run your program in background.